# Tomcat fails to load Java Spark application

Tags: java, tomcat, spark-java

This issue does not relate to Apache Spark, but the Java web framework called Spark.

[image]It's a legacy application of ours which uses Spark Java. When I am trying to deploy in Tomcat it throws the error of not finding Sparkfilter. Where should I check for resolving this issue?

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
   <filter>
   <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>spark.servlet.SparkFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
     <param-name>applicationClass</param-name>
     <param-value>com.example.resource.Spark</param-value>
   </init-param>
 </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>SparkFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>
    <listener>       
      <listener-class>
         com.example.utilities.PropertiesLoader
      </listener-class>
   </listener> 
</web-app>
```

Error in catalina.out

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.resource.Spark.init(Spark.java:121)
    at spark.servlet.SparkFilter.init(SparkFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.initFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:285)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:266)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:108)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4657)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5304)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1875)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I see pom.xml includes the Spark framework. What else should i check to resolve this?

Comment: Can you share a bit more in your issue? Versions? What code are you trying to run? When does the error happen (when you start Tomcat or when you call the app?)  Are you sure it is Apache Spark you are talking about (and not the Spark framework)

Comment: <spark-core-version>2.5</spark-core-version> and Tomcat- apache-tomcat-8.5.37. When I try to run the application from IntelliJ it starts the tomcat server. But when http://localhost:8080/ pops open in the browser. It shows 404

Comment: @jgp do you have any thoughts on this?

Comment: Can you add Spark.java (from com.example.resource.Spark.init) around the lines 121...

Comment: @jgp My tomcat started when I ran it through IntelliJ. Artifact oursservice:war: Deploy took 5,950 milliseconds
13-Feb-2019 10:20:18.243 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/Applications/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/manager]
13-Feb-2019 10:20:18.269 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [/Applications/apache-tomcat-8.5.37/webapps/manager] has finished in [26] ms

Comment: But http://localhost:8080/ throws 404. I am not sure what I am missing

Comment: @jgp I feel I am missing something in my run configuration of tomcat in IntelliJ. But not able to figureout what it is.

Comment: Please let me know, if you need more information

Comment: it appears that `SparkFilter` is able to load your application class `com.example.resource.Spark` however this application class has an NPE at `com.example.resource.Spark.init(Spark.java:121)` did you get a change to check what's in line 121 of this class?

Answer (score 0):

I had also problems starting my sparkjava service in Tomcat 10.
catalina.out shows

```
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/some-service] startup failed due to previous errors
```

and localhost.2022.10.13.log shows

```
    13-Oct-2022 22:07:34.374 SCHWERWIEGEND [Catalina-utility-2] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Ausnahme beim Starten des Filters [SparkFilter]
    java.lang.ClassCastException: class spark.servlet.SparkFilter cannot be cast to class jakarta.servlet.Filter (spark.servlet.SparkFilter is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @41824418; jakarta.servlet.Filter is in unnamed module of loader java.net.URLClassLoader @4e1d422d)
```

I stepped back to Tomcat 9 ... that worked for me.